# Configuring JVM properties for OLP pipelines

Tags: here-olp

I would like to provide custom JVM properties to pipelines deployed to OLP.

I know it is possible when deploying via REST API, but is there any other way to do that (using CLI or portal GUI)?
What are the general rules in that matter? Are different ways of deploying pipelines functionally equal?

Unfortunately, documentation isn't very specific about that. I know this is rather general question without details, but we are trying to figure out the best approach.

Comment: Dalroy, if you mean system properties `-D` then you can follow what ichow suggested of having application.properties or what you suggested with REST API but JVM parameters/ properties (`-X`) can't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, that is not supported.  What would be the use case where you would need to do that?  We can ask for a feature request given a use case.  The different ways of deploying pipelines (CLI, Portal UI) are functionally equivalent.

Comment: What about that: [link](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/pipeline/api-reference-swagger.html)?

I mean, specifically, that part of the JSON:

`customRuntimeConfiguration": "processing.type=live
overwrite=enabled
skipDuplicates=disabled
"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass JVM properties per se (assuming you mean -D arguments to a java command) but you can pass in custom properties for a pipeline version. They will placed in a file named application.properties which your code will then have to read in. [Documentation](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/pipeline/topics/interfacing-with-the-pipeline-process.html#user-configuration)

Comment: the JVM properties (`-X` not system properties `-D`) could change the behavior of JVM for example `-Xms` (changes heap size), `-XX:+UseParallelGC` (change the way GC works), in my opinion, this is not supported in the current implementation, and I think it should not be supported and user should set it from GUI/ CLI. Provided a usecase where it's required, can trigger to ponder about it.